# img src not updating in firefox and edge

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, microsoft-edge

(Not my code)

I was testing out some code I googled out ( [Code Page](http://awardwinningfjords.com/2012/03/08/image-sequences.html) ) and for some reason, while the img src is updating, the image remains the same.

Example > http://awardwinningfjords.com/projects/sequence/apple

```
function rightNow() {
  if (window['performance'] && window['performance']['now']) {
    return window['performance']['now']();
  } else {
    return +(new Date());
  }
}

var fps          = 30,
    currentFrame = 0,
    totalFrames  = 60,
    img          = document.getElementById("myImage"),
    currentTime  = rightNow();

(function animloop(time){
  var delta = (time - currentTime) / 1000;

  currentFrame += (delta * fps);

  var frameNum = Math.floor(currentFrame);

  if (frameNum >= totalFrames) {
    currentFrame = frameNum = 0;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(animloop);

  img.src = "/projects/sequence/particle-hover/particle_hover_04_000" +
    (frameNum < 10 ? "0" : "") + frameNum + ".png";

  currentTime = time;
})(currentTime);
```

Comment: Erk! This is the wrong way of achieving animation! Repaint the images to a `canvas` instead of updating an `img` element!

Comment: The reason why you don't see the image in the viewport update is because setting the `src=""` attribute (and re-rendering the page) is not guaranteed to complete in the time it takes for the animation frame to complete.